# Why am I getting an error trying to insert into a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I'm trying to learn SQL Server and I'm practicing `INSERT INTO`.

When I try to enter this query, it throws an error saying that `[Intern_DB2].[dbo].[MY_Parcels]` is an invalid object.

I had no problems creating this table, why is it saying its invalid all of a sudden?

```
Insert INTO [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[My_Parcels] (ID)
Values (000065, N'test')
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MS SQL, but it looks like you're trying to insert 2/3 values into one. What was your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct database where you are executing the query?

Comment: Your query above is flawed as it's inserting two values into one field `ID`, but that doesn't explain the invalid object error.  Are you connected to the proper server?

Comment: Hang on, I'm just trying to see how to view the original create statement.

Comment: Does MSSQL have case-sensitive tables? Because I'm noticing a difference in capitalization between the error and the INSERT INTO statements.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[My_Parcels]` work?

Comment: @ChrisForrence - MS SQL is not case sensitive by default, but can be configured that way.

Comment: I used the create table GUI function from right clicking the database I'm working in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with your query .

**1st**

```
Insert INTO [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[My_Parcels] (ID)  --<-- Number of columns 1
Values (000065, N'test')                          --<-- Passed values for two columns
```

The number of columns mentioned in your INSERT INTO statement must match the number of values passed in `VALUES` cluase.

**2nd**

You are getting Error message something along the lines `invalid object` which means you have not used the correct Table name or you have created that table in some other database and looking for it in some other database

to check this try Executing the following statement and see if table exists

```
USE INTERN_DB2
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[My_Parcels]
GO
```

Once you have made sure the tables exists , just correct the number of values passed in VALUES claues of your insert statement and it should work.

Comment: You found my error. I can't figure out why, but its saying the table doesn't exist, despite the fact that it shows in my object manager.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that table is created inside `[INTERN_DB2]` database that you are specifying in your insert statement.

Locate your table using GUI, right click select `Script table as` then select `Drop and CREATE to` then select  `New query Editor window`. Once it opens the new query windows verify first line to show `USE [INTERN_DB2]` if it says something else than you created it in wrong database.

In your `INSERT` statement you have listed 1 column, but in `VALUES` you are specifying two different columns. If you want to insert values into two columns, you need to list them out or if you only have two columns than you can remove columns and just add values. This is dangerous because you are assuming the order.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure
VALUES (N'FT', N'Feet', '20080414');
GO

USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure (Name, UnitMeasureCode,
    ModifiedDate)
VALUES (N'Square Yards', N'Y2', GETDATE());
GO
```